# How to re-render list automatically when form is submitted in React.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, forms

I just figured out how to get and post data to database.  The data is displayed in a list when page renders.  I want the list to re render when the form input is submitted.  As of now I have to refresh the page manually in order to get the new item to show in the list.

I have already tried to create a state change in the handleSubmit function.  Nothing seems to happen though.

```
handleSubmit(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  fetch('http://localhost:5000/api/listitems', {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      },
     body: JSON.stringify( {
        //ID : this.state.id,
        Content: this.state.content,
        List_Group: this.state.listgroup,
        Date_Added: this.state.date
      })
    })
    .then(res => res.json())
    .catch(err => console.log(err));
}
```

Below is the form and list code

```
     <h1>Submit an Item</h1>
      <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit} style={formStyle}>
        <label>
          Content:
          <input type="text" value={this.state.content} onChange= 
          {this.handleChange} />
        </label>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
      </form>
      <h1>Grocery List</h1>
      {this.state.items.map(
        (item, i) => 
          <p key={i}>{item.List_Group}: {item.Content}</p>
        )}
```

The list should show the new item on submit automatically.

Comment: Where are you adding new item to the list?

Comment: What are you getting in response?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keeping in mind I have zero practical knowledge of react, it seems to me you simply have to update the `this.state.items` array.

I assume that your component has some sort of `loadItems` method, so I would say that your `then` should look something more like `.then(() => this.loadItems())`

**UPDATED:**

```
  //fetch data from server
  handleData = () => {
    fetch('http://localhost:5000/api/listitems')
       .then(response => response.json())
       .then(data => this.setState({ items: data }));
  }

  //call handleData() on page load
  componentDidMount() {
    this.handleData();
  }

  //this function fires when form is submited
  handleSubmit(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    fetch('http://localhost:5000/api/listitems', {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      },
     body: JSON.stringify( {
        Content: this.state.content,
        List_Group: this.state.listgroup,
        Date_Added: this.state.date
      })
    })
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(() => this.setState({content: ''}))
    //call handleData() when form is submited, which reloads list
    .then(() => this.handleData())
    .then(console.log(this.state.items))
    .catch(err => console.log(err));
  }
```

So the handleData() fetched the data from the server.  It is called in componentDidMount() for the initial page load.  Then it is called again each time the handleSubmit() function is called by the form.  Each time handleData() is called it re-renders the list.

Comment: You were write on this.  I had to call my initial handleData() function which had my get api function.  That function reset the list when called.  I edited your original answer. See above.

Comment: Looks good.  The only note I have is that if you aren't doing anything with the response from the POST, don't bother with `.then(res => res.json())` or alternatively if you want to add some sort of growl-type message, retrieve the json in the following resolver, `.then((jsonResFromPOST) => this.setState({growlMessage: jsonResFromPOST.message}))`.... Also, you should maybe `.catch` the POST earlier and set some friendly error messaging, followed up by reloading the data anyway, in case some new items have come in from another user elsewhere

Answer (score 0):

Set the state of your list of items after getting the response.
here i am assuming that you are getting the whole list in response.

```
handleSubmit(event) {
event.preventDefault();
fetch('http://localhost:5000/api/listitems', {
  method: 'POST',
  headers: {
    'Accept': 'application/json',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
  },
 body: JSON.stringify( {
    //ID : this.state.id,
    Content: this.state.content,
    List_Group: this.state.listgroup,
    Date_Added: this.state.date
  })
})
.then(res => res.json())
.then(data => this.setState({items : data})
.catch(err => console.log(err));
}
```

Comment: So i figured the setState needed to be called somewhere on the items.  I used your example but now React is throwing these errors. It looks like there is an issue passing the data variable to that item state.    `TypeError: this.state.items.map is not a function` `TypeError: this.state.items.map is not a function`

Comment: @DavidSanders Make sure the data which you setting to the items as a state has to be an array.

Comment: I actually figured it out by calling my initial handleData() function instead of the setState

Comment: the setState is in the handleData() so i know in the end the setState is causing a re render but I was having trouble with the new setState to accept the correct data into the array. Calling the handleData() agian just worked.

Answer (score 0):

You need to call this.setState. State updates trigger a rerendering.

```
handleSubmit(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  fetch('http://localhost:5000/api/listitems', {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      },
     body: JSON.stringify( {
        //ID : this.state.id,
        Content: this.state.content,
        List_Group: this.state.listgroup,
        Date_Added: this.state.date
      })
    })
    .then(res => {
      // depending on the response you may need to extract the property here
      this.setState({
         items: res.json(),
      });
    })
    .catch(err => console.log(err));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You may do this:

```
handleSubmit(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  fetch('http://localhost:5000/api/listitems', {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      },
     body: JSON.stringify( {
        //ID : this.state.id,
        Content: this.state.content,
        List_Group: this.state.listgroup,
        Date_Added: this.state.date
      })
    })
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then((items) => this.setState({items: items})) // keep in mind that you may have to transform items to appropriate format to display
    .catch(err => console.log(err));
}
```